# Android, NoSuchFieldError when launching second activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two applications and am turning one into a Library so I can launch it from another application. In my library I have a facebook image and a twitter image that causes the NoSuchFieldError. I have the library defined in my manifest.

```
<activity android:name="com.funayman.listactivity.ApplicationListActivty" />
```

I am starting this activity using

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ApplicationListActivty.class));
```

It seems to find the activity but when it launches I get the following error in LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  731): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.funayman.listactivity.R$id.img_fb
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at com.funayman.listactivity.ApplicationListActivty.onCreate(ApplicationListActivtyActivity.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(  731):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I should point out that if I launch my Library as an application, everything works and loads correctly without any errors.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

I found my issue.  In my library I was using

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Renaming my layout solved my issue.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for asking the same exact question I was about to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`startActivity` with `new Intent(Context, class)` is only applicable if your activity is within the same application. If you want to start an activity from outside of the application, use its full package name.
for example,

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.test.application");
startActivity(i);
```

Also note that you have spelled `Activty` without an 'i' (just pointing out. maybe you deliberately did that?)

Comment: +1 for this priceless piece of information, showing up at the right place & the right time. I am sure this is hiding somewhere in my 718-page book, but yours was much easier to find. Thanks!